# IronPython: How to install IronPython Studio

Tags: ironpython

After installing prerequistes (Visual Studio 2008 Shell Isolated/Integrated Mode Redistributable package) [here](http://ironpythonstudio.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Pre-requisites&referringTitle=Install.), I still get errors: **cannot find one or more components** when installing **IronPython Studio**.

What others do I require? Thx.

Answer (score 2):

See [how-to-use-ironpython-with-visual-studio-2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502173/how-to-use-ironpython-with-visual-studio-2008) and similar questions. It looks like IronPython Studio is supported only with outdated IronPython versions.